# How can I enforce cryptobinding on FreeRADIUS?

Tags: freeradius

On NPS, there's a setting "Disconnect clients without cryptobinding", which should force clients to check the security of the comms which, if I understand correctly, will prevent attacks such as [Sycophant](https://github.com/sensepost/wpa_sycophant).

Is there an equivalent setting on FreeRADIUS/is this necessary/have I misunderstood?